# Bundle error when trying to install Mysql in Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, web-deployment

When running bundle in my Rails application I get the following **error** output in the **command line**:

```
Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
Using mail_form 1.5.1
Installing mysql 2.9.1 with native extensions

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/COPYING
An error occurred while installing mysql (2.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm using:
**rails -v**: 2.2.4

In my **gemfile** I have the following for mysql:

```
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'mysql', '~> 2.9', '>= 2.9.1'

  # Use Capistrano for deployment
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: 'capistrano/rbenv', require: false

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Check the Ruby version($ruby -v) if you get something like this happening, found that mine was locked to and older version of 2.0.0.
To fix this run:

```
$ env | grep PATH
$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: have you tried brew install mysql?

Comment: I get a warning when I try to run that: Warning: mysql-5.7.10 already installed, it's just not linked  @ruby_newbie

Comment: Can you update to the latest bundler and try again?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, I had read in another blog that that worked for some people. Not so much for me.

Comment: try brew uninstall pg, brew install pg, brew update pg, then try bundling.

Comment: So, this ended up being very simple. After uninstalling and reinstalling several gems. I figured out that the ruby version was locked to 2.0.0 for some reason. I've added the fix above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this ended up being very simple. After uninstalling and reinstalling several gems. I figured out that the ruby version was locked to 2.0.0 for some reason. I've added the fix above.